# Single Bigger POST to a google-script or several smaller?

Tags: post, google-apps-script

I have a script which collect some data about certain files in my computer and then make a POST to a google-script published as service.

I was wondering what should be better: collect all the data (which couldn't be more than few MB, maybe 10) and make a single POST, or make one POST request for each piece (which are just some kb) ?

Which is better for performance at both sides, my local computer and for google servers?
Could be understood as abuse if I make a hundred of POST? it will run just once a month.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors that would go into this decision -

- In general, I would argue its better to do one upload as 10mb isn't a large amount of data
- Is this Asynchronous (or automatic) or is there a user clicking button? If its happening automatically then you don't have to worry about reporting progress accurately to the user. If there is a user watching the upload then smaller uploads are better as you'll be able to measure how many of the units (or chunks) are properly uploaded.
- Your computer should not be in the picture at all - Google Apps Script runs on the Google Servers. Perhaps there is some confusion here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know if its asynchronous, but yes, it is automatic, there is no other user than me watching the console output.
My computer is in the picture because, as I said before, there is a script collecting data, and then POST that data to the google script . I know google scripts is at google server side, but this is the second time somebody say that when I mention my computer. Must be something in the other side, isn't it?

Comment: I understand now.. there is some other program on your computer upload to an Apps Script web app. In that case I would still recommend 1 upload if the files is under 10mb - Apps Script also allows you to unzip a file on the server side. See example in this [Issue Tracker item](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2302#c1). This is a bit subjective but I always prefer fewer calls than many calls to the server.

Comment: Ok, so the best way is single upload in most cases.
I'm sorry about asking over asking, but, it's even better when just part of the information will not be needed? I mean, I'm making an index, and every time the script runs, the index is constructed again, and is the google-app-script who takes care if the information sent must be added or not (because it already exists, for example).

Your solution talks about a zipped file, may a single text file would make the same, and more easy work for me

Thanks-